# Find out what keeps changing my MAC address on reboot

Tags: networking, mac-address

Some time ago I installed `macchanger` to play around with some wifi stuff. Soon after that I uninstalled it again (with giving 'purge' to `apt`), together with everything else I installed before around that time. Now my wifi device mac address still keeps changing on each reboot, which I do not want.

I already seeked for some config which contains anything about mac addresses with `sudo grep -EHirn "[^a-zA-Z_]mac[^b-zB-Z_]" /etc/*`, but no useful results so far.

How do I find out which program is causing that changes and how to stop that?

**Edit:**
NetworkManager does not seem to be responsible (I am just typing this over wifi connection, whose connection is set up by wicd):

```
$ nmcli c  
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  da9f42c3-c083-38b6-8b1d-b8358e707b7a  ethernet  --
```

**EDIT 2**: This box is running Devuan 4, if that's important for anyone.

Comment: Is there any left-over from macchanger? You could search: `find / -type f -iname '*maccahnger*'` and if something turns up, there might be your problem.

Comment: It is known that a random value of the ether number (aka MAC address or HWaddress) is generated for each new connection in **Movile Phones** it is not complex, it is by default automatic,  and it is required in IPv6. It is quite simple to activate by several programs. A simple `sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:00:2d:3a:2a:28` would change it. A random value is not difficult to construct from `/etc/urandom`. It is difficult to guide you in any specific direction given the wide range of possibilities. Do you have more specific information?

Comment: no macchanger leftovers

Answer (score 2):

Modern versions of NetworkManager can randomize the MAC address on WiFi connections without any extra utilities.

The parameter is named `802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization`, and you can check it with:

```
nmcli c show <connection name> | grep 802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization
```

You should replace the `<connection name>` with the actual name of your WiFi connection configuration. (If unsure about the name, type `nmcli c` to see the list of connection definitions.)

The `nmcli` command can (and should) be used with your regular user account, **not** as root.

The value can be "default" (0) to obey NetworkManager's global default setting on WiFi MAC randomization, "never" (1) to use the interface's normal address, or "always" (2) to explicitly require MAC address randomization for this WiFi connection.

You could disable the randomization for a particular connection with:

```
nmcli c mod <connection name> 802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization never
```

or by changing the global defaults, by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (this requires root access) to add:

```
[connection]
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization=never
```

The upstream "factory default" for NetworkManager is to not randomize WiFi MAC addresses unless asked to do so (to avoid surprises when upgrading from older versions of NetworkManager that did not have this feature), but some distributions have changed the default settings, in order to protect the user's privacy by default.

There is also a separate setting for randomizing the MAC address during a wireless network scan. If necessary, that can be disabled by adding this to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

---

[`macchanger`](https://github.com/alobbs/macchanger/) doesn't seem to persist its settings in any way on its own. Are you sure you haven't added any other MAC randomization scripts or tools? Check the directories `/etc/wicd/scripts/*` and `/etc/network/if-*.d/` for possible add-on scripts, and perhaps `/etc/rc.local` if it exists.

Comment: NetworkManager does not seem to be responsible (I am just typing this over wifi connection, whose connection is set up by wicd), see above edit.

Comment: (adding the suggested config line then also did not make any difference)

Comment: The fact that you use `wicd` instead of NetworkManager to manage your WiFi interface is important information that **you should edit into your question**. You should also mention the name and version of your Linux distribution.

Comment: Wicd was already edited in, before your comment. Sorry it made your answer less important, I am not aware that NetworkManager would be a default.

Comment: According to [Devuan 4 Release Notes](https://files.devuan.org/devuan_chimaera/Release_notes.txt) NetworkManager would indeed be the default for Devuan 4 if you used xfce, mate, cinnamon or kde via plasma-nm. The Release Notes also say that `wicd` is no longer available in Devuan 4, since it depends on obsolete Python 2. But apparently this has changed since initial release, as the [package search for wicd in Devuan](https://pkginfo.devuan.org/cgi-bin/policy-query.html?c=package&q=wicd&x=submit) indicates there's a version of it in the `chimaera/main` repository section.

Comment: You could try these commands: `sudo dmesg|grep MAC` and perhaps `journalctl -u NetworkManager | grep MAC` to make sure NetworkManager is not the culprit.

Comment: "Devuan GNU+Linux is a fork of Debian without systemd", so no journalctl. `dmesg` unfortunately does not show anything for the wifi MAC.

Comment: no scripts in any of the dirs, nothing started by rc.local